# Matching MD5 from Azure to On-prem with POWERSHELL 5

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage, md5, powershell-5.1

(note: yes, I know it's powershell 5 and not 7. Due to our infosec policies getting this done is non-trivial, so please don't say "well just upgrade")

I need to match the on-prem MD5 with the azure MD5. The code I've been using doesn't match and I can't figure out why.

local:

```
$file = 'myfilename'
$localMd5 = Get-FileHash -Path ($file).FullName -Algorithm MD5
$rawMD5 = $localMd5.hash
```

azure:

```
$azureBlobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container "mycontainer" -Context $Ctx
$azureBlob = $azureBlobs | Where-Object { (split-path $_.name -Leaf) -eq $file.Name }
$azureblob.ICloudBlob.FetchAttributes() 
#two different ways to get the md5, both match
$azureBlob.ICloudBlob.Properties.ContentMD5
[Convert]::ToBase64String($azureblob.BlobProperties.ContentHash)
```

Both azure methods return `rs61TPrLkHTm93mhTRS90w==`

However, using various methods WITH POWERSHELL 5.1 all give the same value, none of which match what I'm seeing in azure.

The hash given by get-filehash is `B0569E57A3DB20FD1914965865DC0E42`

If I use these two methods, I get the same result: `sFaeV6PbIP0ZFJZYZdwOQg==`

```
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001.SoapHexBinary]::Parse($rawMD5).Value)

[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([byte[]] -split ($localmd5.hash -replace '..', '0x$& '))
```

At this point I'm stumped. I've done it with 2 different files, so I don't think it's the files, I think it's the code.

Comment: Read followng.  Had same issue : https://powers-hell.com/2021/12/31/calculate-validate-md5-hashes-on-azure-blob-storage-files-with-powershell/?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng yeah, I read through that. The problem I'm running into is that I don't have access to those functions (Powershell 5.1 doesn't have them, he's using Powershell 7), and the substitutions i've found work, but are providing different results.

Comment: I was refereeing to this : Azure stores the file hash value in the CONTENT-MD5 tag as a base64 encoded representation of the binary MD5 hash value, whereas when we compute the MD5 value locally, the output of the hash is a hex representation of the binary hash value…

Comment: @jdweng yup. I tried using multiple ways to convert the values, and in no case do they actually match. Which makes me wonder what the heck I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @mbourgon can't you use something like $MD5 = [System.Security.Cryptography.MD5]::Create() to create an MD5 object and then use the ComputeHash method? This takes a byte array OR a filestream as input and will result in a byte array with the hash (so no conversion required)

Comment: I take it you've confirmed the local file is actually the same content as the one in Azure Storage? Have you tried to download the blob to a fresh local copy and use ```Get-FileHash``` on *that*  just to sanity-check the assumption?

Comment: Yup! I'm an idiot! There should be only one copy of the file - and somehow a slightly different version got uploaded.  I didn't think to sanity check it, and the freaking length doesn't even match! Using a THIRD file that I verified matches, my examples above work. Sorry to waste everyone's time.

Comment: Heh. At least you've got some pointers on how to compare the hashes now when the files *do* actually match :-)